# Alternative to the Regcode module?

Tags: 7, users

I'd really like to use the [Regcode module](http://drupal.org/project/regcode), but it is not very well maintained and with the progression of depending modules like VBO it becomes rather unstable imho.

So, i'd be glad if anyone can point me in the right direction to solve these problems:

1. Restrict user registration to "somehow invited" (preferably code-based) people only.
2. Manage the invites in backend.

I'd also like to know if there's maybe a commercial module that fit my needs...

Comment: could you add a bit more information on your ideal process?  as you've explained it so far I would think you should just limit new user creation to administrators and then email a Welcome email to the new users...

Comment: This would be a hassle. :) The client wants to invite the potential users (hundreds if thousands) via postal service and send them a sort of "invitation code". So if they can manage these codes in the backend (like with the regcode mod, they would see, if and who used the code). Actually the module is exactly what i need, except in terms of reliability. (Rules integration throws errors and the latest VBO is just not working with regcode...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need to do some custom magic voodoo ;)

I built a similar site earlier this year:   The client provided a list of users (with their email addresses) in an Excel spreadsheet.  I created a new column with a unique 8 character registration code for each user.  I then imported that file, including the code, as new users.

The registration code was saved as a plain-text field in their user profile.

Create a custom user login form that only requires the registration code,  mail out the reg codes.

Comment: Definitely worth a thought... :) How did you import the users? http://drupal.org/project/user_import ? Unfortunately this doesn't support Profile2 yet... which is also part of my concept (but not set in stone)

Comment: The user accounts were very minimal and this was a one-time import.  I bootstrapped drupal and  wrote a simple CSV importer that created users with the standard drupal functions.

Comment: thanks, i'll look into it and maybe start doing magic :)